# how to add certificate and keys and service identities in windows azure?

Tags: azure

I am developing one asp.net website and I will be hosting the site on windows azure. My requirement is when user access the site like *www.xyz.com\admin* then live id authentication should happen but when the user access the site *www.xyz.com* then no need do authentication.

After referring to an MSDN document I come to know about ACS with  WIF, so I created the namespace and did so on so on.

But whenever I am accessing the federation URL (https://xyz.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml) I am getting error:

> ID:1089 unable to connect the remote server.

I unfortunately deleted the certificate and keys and service identities in windows azure I don't know how to get it back, also I don't how do fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted the certificates and keys they all you need is to just create new one(s). You can either use Self Signed certificates, or use X.509 certificates issued by a trusted Certificate Authority. Once you get your X.509 certificate (it shall include a private key) you can upload it in the ACS management portal (which is locate at https://xyz.accesscontrol.windows.net/):

[image: ACS Service Certificates]

The FederationMedatadata.xml cannot be generated without the Token Signing certificate.

Or, the easiest for you, would be to just delete that namespace and create a new one.